# Нет команд ROUND и SUM в SQL Shell (psql)

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql, pgadmin

Смотрел видео-урок, лишних действий не делал. По какой-то причине не работают команды ROUND и SUM, проверял другие команды - проблема именно в этих командах. Помогите решить.

SQL, PostgreSQL, pgAdmin 4, базы данных.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Должно работать. Судя по всему, команда не дополнена — в строке `(#` можно заметить. Попробуйте перезапустить `Psql shell`